What size joists to use
I have an old house where I have to replace the existing 2x6 joists but I am not able to upsize the joist. Will a two ply 2x6x12 on 12” o.c be good enough? It’s for a second storey floor joist. Only putting two bedrooms and a jack/jill bathroom above these joists.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You likely will need a real structural engineer to look at it and determine what would meet local code.

2x6s is pushing it for safety with a 12ft span.  An engineer might suggest one of the newer joist types or steel beams/joists.  A floor that might have some bounce/sag in it will limit finish flooring choices to carpet/sheet vinyl.

Why do you have to replace the existing joists?

First things first: since you are replacing joists, this will require a  building permit and it's up to the local building commissioner to tell you what's OK or not. What the building commissioner will allow depends on many factors, for example if this is a community with tons of old houses and the commissioner himself/herself is used to the types of compromises that have to be made when repairing/restoring old houses, or if this near an urban center with old houses selling for >$1M and the building commissioner just assumes you can afford bringing the house up to code. So whatever anybody answers is a moot point without you first checking with your building officer.
Having said that:
It depends on the wood species, the grade, the deflection limit and the live load standards at your locale. But assuming SPF No. 2 with 40psf live load, your proposal is right at the limit anyway (I think the limit is 11'-6"), making it again, up to the opinion of the building official. But even if they allow it, you might not want to do it like that, as crip659 says on the comments, because a bouncy floor will limit your options. Alternatives:

Install a metal beam in the middle, and then you'll have a span of 6', which is totally within the range of 2x6 at 16" o.c.
Do a combination of raising the floor and lowering the ceiling below, just by 1" each, so that you can fit 2x8s, which can span 12'. (thinking of it, in many old houses joists were built from rough-sawn lumber, so you might actually have 6" of space, meaning you only have to increase 3/4" each way to fit a 7-1/2 2x8)

